# What is the meaning of 'put it on your mama'?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I would like to know the meaning of 'put it on your mama' in the movie The Upside.

> Phil: That is the money for Untitled Number Zero, Or What Is Bravery. Which is now proudly hung in Carter’s trophy room.
>   (Phil gives Dell 50,000 dollars. 'Untitled Number Zero, Or What Is Bravery' is Dell's painting. Phil sold it to his neighbor, Carter.)
>   Dell: For real?
>   Phil: For real.
>   Dell: For keeps?
>   Phil: For keeps.
>   Dell: **For... Put it on your mama?**
>   Phil: **Put it on your mama?**
>   Dell: Yo, P, this is... this is crazy, man. Hell yeah, man! Hell yeah, P!

And they change the subject.
I don't understand the meaning of 'put it on your mama'.
Please help me. I would be grateful.

Comment: As it is put in your query, it seems that Phil does not understand it either. What are further lines?

Comment: I added the further lines, but they don't help.

Comment: My shot is (mind, I am not a native!): _Do you **put** (swear) (it) **on your momma**'s life that this is true?_

Comment: UrbanDictionary suggests that "would you put it on your mama?" can be a variant of "would you swear on your mother's grave?"

Comment: Thank you so much, Mv Log and Gary Botnovacan! You saved my life!

Answer (score 3):

To put something "on my/your momma" is apparently an American black slang expression used to imply that something is 100% true.  It is roughly equivalent to (or perhaps a shortened version of) "swear (something) on your mother's grave".

Here's a [humorous twitter video](https://twitter.com/supremedreams_1/status/991105050469691392?lang=en) explaining the significance of this expression (warning: strong language).

In the movie, Dell (who is black) uses this expression to ask Phil if he's serious about the money.  Phil initially seems to have no idea what Dell means by "put it on your momma", but he quickly understands the gist of it.